# TFS Build Summary Notification with Attachment Link

Tags: tfs, azure-devops, azure-pipelines, tfsbuild, tfs-2015

How i can add attachment link in TFS Build notification email? I have TFS 2017 on-premises installed. I have tried by making changes in xls file but it didnt worked. i will be grateful to you if anyone can help me with this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find the email templates in `%PROGRAMFILES%\Microsoft Team Foundation Server 2015\Application Tier\TFSJobAgent\Transforms` and modify them the way you want. In this folder you'll find the **build completion events xsl** files.

The build events expose a Url property, which shows the hyperlink in the email.

---

Besides, you could also choose to use some 3rd-party extension to send E-mail Notification.

- [Send Email](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=dutchworkz.SendEmail)
- [Other Extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/search?term=email&target=AzureDevOps&category=All%20categories&sortBy=Relevance)

Those tasks they send an email to the address(es) you defined in your pipeline. **You can defined the contents of the message yourself**.